# Access violation reading location without location

Tags: c++

Well, i have two functions

```
void RealFunction()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "RealFunction()", "Trace", MB_OK);
}

void FakeFunction()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "FakeFunction()", "Trace", MB_OK);
}
```

and when i try to do that i get access violation error

```
void main()
{
    DWORD target = (DWORD)RealFunction;
    DWORD trampoline = (DWORD)Trampoline;
    cout << target + " - " + trampoline << endl;
}
```

I don't know why it is even throwing access violation while i am trying to cout a DWORD ?

Comment: which line cause the error? can you break it down and identify what cause the error?

Comment: @BryanChen it is the `length` function in `iosfwd`

Comment: The reason is that `RealFunction` is not a `DWORD`. I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JacobSeleznev, look at the answer below...

Answer (score 2):

```
DWORD target = (DWORD)RealFunction;
DWORD trampoline = (DWORD)Trampoline;
cout << target + " - " + trampoline << endl;
```

You must've meant `<<` instead of `+`.

You have a `const char *`, the string literal containing a dash. To that, you're adding two, likely fairly large numbers, with the result being some absurd memory address, which is interpreted as a string pointer. Undefined behavior.